# Trigger when Date Changes in Different TimeZones

Tags: java, timezone

One of my business use case requires to recalculate some metrics on date change and also need to cover clients working on different time zones like EDT, IST etc.

Is there any option in Java to get a trigger on a date change and should work for different time zone?

Example: I want a trigger for date change in IST, EDT, GMT, MST, CST etc only. and not all time zones. Is there any jar or a framework which supports this where i can input the time zones and i just get notifications.

I cannot use cron triggers here because it works on a single timezone. Cron expression takes a particular time zone.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate when the date changes , usually server times are fixed to a standard timezone (UTC or EST etc)? Is it passed as a parameter for your calculation , based on some logic ? Do you have any scenarios where the timezone changes on a end user system ?

Comment: My scenario is I need a trigger/notification  when my server time clocks 12:00 AM  in IST, 12:00 AM in EDT, 12:00 AM in GMT every day.

Comment: What do you use for scheduling ? Quartz or Timer or any other API ? Based on that you can actually set up a schedule to do it on any timezone that you want.

Comment: I use Quartz scheduler, but if i need to work on 10 timezone, I need to schedule 10 timers which is very difficult to maintain. So i am checking for any framework availability. If is just give different time zone, I need to get notification on just one listener. I can build my own but i am checking for already any available framework which can do this for me.